# creating view on table enhance the query performance on sql 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

what will happen when I query a view in sql 2000?
Does it query the underlying table? Is making a view on table fasten the query execution?

There is a table with 10 million records(Records from 2005 to till date).

The users are often interested in the current year data.So if i create a view on the table,only using the current year data then would that increase the query performance,while querying the view  ?

I mean instead of querying the table with where condition year='2013' , the user can query the view and get better performance?

Comment: Views (without any other work) are like macros - they don't have any of their own storage, and they're effectively "expanded out" into the body of the query they appear in, before that query is optimized.

Answer (score 3):

As Damien stated in his comment, the definitions of views are expanded and the query used to build them is "inlined" into your own query, so it is unlikely that you will get any performance increase by using a standard view.

An alternative is to create an indexed view, which is a standard view that has a clustered index created on it, effectively materialising it and making it act as if it were a table.  In non-enterprise editions of SQL server you need to use the NOEXPAND hint when referencing the indexed view to make the optimiser take the index into account, but you can get performance gains this way.

There are special considerations for indexed views, certain settings and conditions that must be set for them to work, it's all detailed here:

[Creating an Indexed View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Good one.  I had completely forgotten that Indexed Views were available in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Does index view available in sql 2000?

Comment: Yes, please look at the article, it's a SQL Server 2000 article